# How to find the nearest parent element attribute value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am facing a problem on getting the nearest parent element attribute value using **Jquery**. Can anyone help me on this. My element structure is as below,

```
<ul class="Someclass">
<li><span id=3 class="heading"></span>
  <ul>
    <li>
     <ul> <li><span ><button onclick= "redirect()"></button></span</li>
     <ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect() {
    alert(....)
}
</script>
```

In the above code when i click that element having `onclick` event i want to get the value as 3 in `alert()` which is in the element having the class **heading**. The above code is in for loop so it will have more code like this in a same page.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: i tried using closest and parent too but i am not able to get exactly. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code, pass the clicked element reference to the function like

```
<button onclick= "redirect(this)">asdf</button>
```

then

```
function redirect(el) {
    alert($(el).closest('.Someclass > li').children('span').attr('id'))
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F2B55/)

Bu a more recommended way will be is to use jQuery event handlers like

```
<button class="redirect">asdf</button>
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.Someclass .redirect').click(function(){
        alert($(this).closest('.Someclass > li').children('span').attr('id'))
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HZ3gb/)

Comment: Instead closest can i use parent? because sometimes there will be some other class with same name closest to that element.

Comment: @VinothBabu it will be better if you can add a unique class to that ul

Comment: Thats difficult in this case. Is it possible to get using parent()?

Comment: @PaulD. that will be same as `.closest()` in result

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh indeed, my bad. Thanks for noting that ! Some differences between the two are explained here http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @VinothBabu you need to have a unique way to locate  the `li` element... anyway have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F2B55/2/

Answer (score 3):

Give this Try

```
function redirect(elem) {
    alert($(elem).closest('.Someclass > li').children('span').attr('id'))
}
```

Change Markup to this:

```
<li><span><button onclick= "redirect(this)"></button></span</li>
```

`this` will reffer to the current object in `DOM`
By wrapping `elem` in `$(elem)` will convert it to jQuery object then you can traverse to the closest and find `span`

You can also filter that `span` with `.children('span:first')`

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4RqcZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
alert($(this).closest('.heading').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".someclass li").click(function(){
   $(this).closet('.heading').attr('id');

})
```

Answer (score 0):

could you pass it on as a parameter to your redirect function? You'd somehow hold that value in a variable in your loop.

Comment: yup i ll pass this in parameter.

Comment: if it works, please mark it as correct so others will quickly find a solution. Either this or another. Whichever works best

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution if you can change the `id` and `class` to parent `li`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/4RqcZ/2/)**

More about **[parent selector](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)**

**Jquery**

```
function redirect(elem) {
    var myid = $(elem).parents(".heading").attr("id");
    alert(myid);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="Someclass">
<li id="3" class="heading">
  <ul>
    <li>
     <ul> <li><span ><button onclick="redirect(this)" id="haha">Go</button></span</li>
     <ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<ul>
```